# How to send variable amount of ether to smart contract from React front end?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to send a variable amount of ether from my React front end to my smart contract.  In remix, I can do this no problem by just selecting the amount and sending it with the function

In my front end, this is the function where values.amount is 100wei

```
const sendEth = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  try {
    const { ethereum } = window;

    if (ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, escrowAbi.abi, signer);
      let nftTxn = await connectedContract.depositEth(values.amount);
        
      console.log("Mining...please wait.", nftTxn)
      await nftTxn.wait();
      
      console.log(`Mined, see transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/${nftTxn.hash}`);
      // console.log(connectedContract)

    } else {
      console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist!");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

}

In my smart contract this is my depositEth function - however msg.value is argument i want to pass but I can't pass this as an argument to this function?

FYI in my app, once you they pay eth to the contract it will release an NFT.

```
 function depositEth() public payable hasToken(address(this), nftAddress)  {
        require(msg.value == amountOwed, 'You ow more money');
        buyerAddress = payable(msg.sender);

        if(walletHoldsToken(address(this),nftAddress)) {
         ERC721(nftAddress).safeTransferFrom(address(this), buyerAddress, tokenID);
        }
    }
```

So what I am asking is how do I send x amount of eth to a contract with that value defined in the front end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your smart contract define a function to return the amount that owed:

```
function getOwedAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
    // i  am assuming " amountOwed" is state variable, uint256
    return amountOwed;
  }
```

After creating the contract.

```
const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, escrowAbi.abi, signer)
```

get the owned amount

```
let owedAmount = await contract.getOwedAmount();
owedAmount=owedAmount.toString()
let transaction=await connectedContract.depositEth({value:owedAmount})
await transaction.wait();
```

since `depositEth` is payable we can pass last argument as an object specifying how much we send and solidity will automatically assign that amount to `msg.value`

Answer (score 1):

Your `depositEth()` function takes 0 params, so the JS snippet also needs to pass 0 params.

There's the [overrides](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend) object in `ethers`, always passed after the regular function params (in your case on the 1st place as there are 0 params), allowing to modify certain fields of the transaction invoking the function, including its `value`.

```
let nftTxn = await connectedContract.depositEth({
    value: values.amount
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call parseEther from ethers library.

```
let nftTxn = await connectedContract.depositEth(address, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0000000000000001") });
```

//sends 100 wei await transaction.wait()